# Setting timeout for postman collections

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I want to run the Postman collection with timeout enabled at the collection level.
Is this setting possible at the collection level in Postman?
I know that the **timeout** can be set per request using  `setTimeout(() => {}, 15000)`, but I could not find something similar to run the collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Request timeout for single call**
>
> Postman has a setting that you set manually in Settings > General > Request timeout in ms that you can set if you want to set an explicit timeout. However, you won’t be able to do what you’re trying to do from a script.
>
> You can, however, write request tests to make sure your response times
> are under a certain threshold. That way when you run the request, the
> test will fail if it’s slower than say, 800ms:

```js
pm.test("Response time is less than 800ms", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(800);
});
```

According to https://community.postman.com/t/request-timeout-for-single-call/6881/2